# Connect to a running JBoss AS7 instance for test purposes

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I already have a integration-test phase, when I ran the selenium tests. I also want to run some unit tests in this phase, because the app is too much complex and have a lot of dependencies between his modules (a hell), so, after a week fighting against OpenEJB and Arquillian, I believe that this would be easier.

The thing is: how do I made it work?

I have the instance already running, if I instantiate an InitialContext and try to lookup some bean, I got an exception telling me that I have not set the `java.naming.initial.factory`, and I don't know what to put in there.

I'm also complaining about the annotated beans.

Suppose a Bean like this:

```
@Stateless
public class ABeanImpl implements ABean {
  @EJB
  private BBean;
}
```

Will the container automatically get right the `BBean`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to connect to JBoss 7.1 remote JNDI:**

Here is the code snippet that I use for JBoss 7.1:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
String JBOSS_CONTEXT = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JBOSS_CONTEXT);
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jboss");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jboss123");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

**Resolution of ambiguous ejb references:**

According to [JBoss EJB 3 reference](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/EJB_Ref_Resolution.html), if at any level of your EJB environment (EJB/EAR/Server) are duplicates in used interfaces, exception will be thrown during resolution of injected beans.

Based on above, if you have got a reference to EJB bean which interface:

- has two implementations in your EJB module (JAR/WAR) - exception will be thrown
- has two implementations in your application (other EJB JAR's in same EAR) - exception will be thrown
- has two implementations, one in module with bean **ABeanImpl**, second somewhere else - implemetation from current module is used.